# Oracle dropping and recreating synonyms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When we use CTAS like this:

```
create table big2 as select * from big1; 
drop table big1;
rename big2 to big1;
```

If there are synonym existing on big1, do we need to drop synonym on big1 prior to delete and recreate them? Or is this not necessary?

Comment: just call `create synonym` and see if it fails. Testing it would have been faster than writing down your question here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Becuase Synonym is just another name you give to an object ( either within your schema or not). See this code below.

(BTW, shouldn't you rename table t2 to t1 directly?? Does your CTAS have other where conditions, which you are not showing here?)

```
SQL> create table t1 as
  2  select * from scott.emp;

Table created.

SQL> select count(*) from t1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL> select count(*) from t2;
select count(*) from t2
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> create synonym s1 for t1;

Synonym created.

SQL> create table t2 as
  2  select * from t1;

Table created.

SQL> drop table t1;

Table dropped.

SQL> alter table t2 rename to t1;

Table altered.

SQL> select count(*) from t1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL> select count(*) from s1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14
```